# Implementing Spring Switch User Filter with cas

Tags: java, spring-security, cas

I'm new to Spring security and cas.
In my project I have a cas(CenteralAuthenticationServer) server and a service server.
I want to implement Switch user filter for some users in my application.
Where I should put these lines?

```
<bean id="switchUserProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter">
 <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
 <property name="switchUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_switch_user" />
 <property name="exitUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_exit_user" />
 <property name="targetUrl" value="/index.jsp" />
</bean>
```

In my cas project or in my web application?
Should I tell tomcat to use this filter in web.xml?
Is there any implementation example?
Should I create java class to implement this fitler?

Answer (score 0):

Add it in your web application (dispatcher-servlet.xml). Check this example if you need. 
[switch user link](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Switch-User-Functionality-in-Spring)

Comment: some example code in your answer would be good.  links can go stale